# Add IN clause to join specification

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Here is the existing code and I need to pass the List of order types instead of one orderType. And this specification is already added to the `WHERE` clause of the existing search query.

How to modify the existing specification for the `IN` clause?

```
public static Specification<OrderEntity> addReference(String orderType, String refNum) {
  return (root, query, builder) -> {
    if (null != refType && null != refNum) {
      Join<OrderEntity, OrderDetailEntity> orderSearchJoin =
                root.join(OrderEntity_.orderDetailEntityList);
      query.distinct(true);      
      return builder.and(
                builder.equal(orderSearchJoin.get(OrderDetailEntity_.orderType), orderType),
                builder.equal(orderSearchJoin.get(OrderDetailEntity_.referenceNum), refNum));
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be the answer to your question:

```
public static Specification<OrderEntity> addReference(List<String> orderTypes, List<String> refNums) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> {
            if (null != orderTypes && !orderTypes.isEmpty() && null != refNums && !refNums.isEmpty()) {
                Join<OrderEntity, OrderDetailEntity> orderSearchJoin =
                        root.join(OrderEntity_.orderDetailEntityList);
                query.distinct(true);
                return builder.and(orderSearchJoin.get(OrderDetailEntity_.orderType).in(orderTypes),
                        orderSearchJoin.get(OrderDetailEntity_.referenceNum).in(refNums));
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
```

Reference:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Join.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html